# How to check if mysqli_connect was successful or not?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm writing an installer script and I need to check if the user entered correct database information and therefore need to check if mysqli_connect was successful or not. A simple if-else will suffice.

Comment: Try the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php).

Comment: possible duplicate? [testing php/mysqli connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678650/testing-php-mysqli-connection)

Comment: read mysqli_connect from the PHP manual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so:

```
if( ! $db = mysqli_connect(...) ) {
    die('No connection: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Answer (score 5):

What about this:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
?>
```