# Custom handling of mysqli_connect bad settings

Tags: php

I am currently using this code to hide mysqli_connect() errors.

`error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',0);`

But with reporting ON, when I introduce an incorrect setting into a mysqli_connect() param the usual gibberish appears. Is it possible to display a message of my own such as "Check DB connection settings" rather than the garble you usually get IF mysqli_connect() fails?

I presume this is done with try/catch. Can anyone shed some light on this with of how I might do the above?

Could be along the lines of pseudo `If mysqli_connect bad settings, echo "bad settings please check".`

Thanks.

Comment: Have you read the manual yet? There's a [`->connect_error`](http://www.php.net/mysqli.construct) to probe for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if mysqli\_connect was successful or not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15028757/how-to-check-if-mysqli-connect-was-successful-or-not)

Comment: OK OK... Now lets bring on the downvotes shall we?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd") or die("THIS IS THE ECHOED MESSAGE");
```

You can also use this:

```
$conn= mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd") or die("SOME PREAMBLE: " . mysqli_error($conn));
```