# Why does a new mysqli object return false if it did work?

Tags: php, mysqli

maybe you can enlighten me. Is there a good explanation why the mysqli object returns false if it did work and true if it didn't?

Code:

```
$connection= @new mysqli($ip, $user, $password);

if (!$connection)
{
    $connection->select_db($db);
    $connection->set_charset("utf8");
}
```

Why is this correct and not `if ($connection)`?

Comment: It isn't correct. It should be `if ($connection)`.

Comment: Do you understand the meaning of the @ or !   ? Read the docs

Comment: I guess this is the correct way to check if you've connected successfully: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3678682/679227